# Sending tests to myself using scripts.google.com and not getting the button

Tags: email, google-schemas

Do you have to be registered before you can even test the email markup? I am trying to send a test to myself using the apps-script tutorial. I sent the email to myself using scripts.google.com and while I get the email in my gmail account, it does not include the button. I'm using the exact example for the Go-to/View action button listed here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial#creating_the_project

It requested authorization, which I granted and then re-ran it. Still no button. I am a google apps domain user, so my address is me@mydomain.com, and I DO see buttons on emails I get from other companies just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to send an email with "working" actions you do need to go through registration and white listing process. However, you can test the correctness of your action, using [gmail-actions](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com) where you'd be able to test either the full email you are trying to send or just an action

You'd need to login with your gmail credentials